# What is a non-sexual word for a smug, domineering woman (could be any gender) that takes pleasure in harming others from a position of power?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Dominatrix by root would fit but has become intrinsically related to S&M.
I'm thinking of a former Human Resources director, who created a Vice Presidential role for herself - that mindset. She attempted to "take me down" and terminate me, only to be defeated in arbitration.

> Our former HR Director was a ______, taking great pleasure in eliminating employees, as she felt was her right.

Thesaurus.com's #2 definition is correct, *a woman who dominates, oppresses, or behaves in a dictatorial way.* but I need a word that does NOT have sexual connotations.

I tried thesaurus.com, synonym.com, and apparently Roget's Thesaurus Online has "died", per a link to a 1999 web page.

I found, deep within answers to a similar (but NOT duplicate) question the answer of IMPERIOUS, which with the https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/imperiousf definition seems to fit the bill. She was hired by committee into the HR role, and against logic, into the VP role as well, so that part was justified. Just not all of the tyrannical behaviour that came with it all. ;)

SOLVED ENOUGH. Thanks to all.

Comment: What about ***virago***? https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/virago

Comment: Your question is self-contradictory. You want a non-sexual term specific to a woman.

Comment: Do you want a term specific to a woman, or a general term that can suit either gender? People seem confused about this.

Comment: @StuartF - ***woman***  is clearly cited in the headline. Then “*I'm thinking of a former Human Resources director, who created a Vice Presidential role for **herself** - that mindset. **She** attempted to "take me down" and terminate me, only to be defeated in arbitration.*” what more do you need to understand the OP refers to a female human being?

Comment: I want a non-sexual (related to sexual activity) term, not a gender or non-gender specific term, but in this case it IS about a woman tyrant. I guess I can live with tyrant, but it was the specific self-satisfaction that she would take in causing grief for another that pushes it to the domineering.

Comment: Either, neither, just a good fully descriptive word. One who IS domineering and finds self-satisfaction in it, who feels it is CERTAINLY her right to do so (gloating) and one should not attempt to question that authority. Too bad for her, I did. And I was... Victorious.  She was so self-assured that she did not follow the rules of due diligence.

Comment: Is a *nurse Ratched* still recognized as a thing?

Comment: No one has yet suggested _bully_ which describes the misuse of power to gain pleasure or satisfaction. _Bullying_ is often thought to involve physical harm, or the threat of it, but misusing the power of a superior position or stronger personality is bullying as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would refer to such a person as a:

- petty tyrant (or just "tyrant")
- petty authoritarian
- malicious control freak
- power hungry bitch

I think all those fit nicely into your statement. And none have sexual connotations.

> Our former HR Director was a ______, taking great pleasure in eliminating employees, as she felt was her right.

---

### tyrant

> 2b: one resembling an oppressive ruler in the harsh use of authority or power
>
> <sup>https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tyrant</sup>

Comment: "Bitch" is definitely sexist.

Comment: @Greybeard, the requirement was "not sexual". This answer meets that requirement. "Sexist" is something else.

Comment: There seems some confusion about whether the OP wants a female-specific term or not. The heading mentions a woman but it doesn't specify that the term must be female-specific, just that the OP wants to describe a person they know who is female. Regardless, I'm not sure that here (under this answer) is the place to discuss if the question should be closed/is a duplicate.

Comment: It would be useful if this answer explained the different meaning and connotations of each suggestion, as the four phrases are not equivalent.

Comment: She ("i") meant this person, who is female, but would likely have bad behaviour either way, seemed to take a particular sense of pride and self-satisfaction in her role in eliminating employees that got on her bad side somehow. Personally, I would judge a male or female or other all in the same way, if they were in a power position acting in a similar manner. I have no bias for nor against BECAUSE she is a woman, it is just happenstance.

Comment: If I were just going for female-specific, you could think "ball breaker", but now find a term that is not gender influenced. Much luck! :)